# jboss memcacehd kryo flex

Tags: apache-flex, jboss, memcached, kryo

I have a jboss 5.1 AS in which i m trying to implement session replication with memcached and kryo serialization . Everything is working fine , but i have a page in my application which has to its left some flex features . When i click on this page in the GUI , kryo serialization failes with the following stack trace :

```
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.SerializationException: Unable to serialize object of type: flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:493)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serialize.MapSerializer.writeObjectData(MapSerializer.java:104)
    at de.javakaffee.kryoserializers.CopyForIterateMapSerializer.writeObjectData(CopyForIterateMapSerializer.java:56)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Serializer.writeObject(Serializer.java:43)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:520)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.SerializationException: Unable to serialize object of type: flex.messaging.SessionMetricsTracker
Serialization trace:
destroyedListeners (flex.messaging.HttpFlexSession)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:493)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serialize.CollectionSerializer.writeObjectData(CollectionSerializer.java:86)
    at de.javakaffee.kryoserializers.CopyForIterateCollectionSerializer.writeObjectData(CopyForIterateCollectionSerializer.java:46)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serialize.FieldSerializer.writeObjectData(FieldSerializer.java:175)at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serialize.ReferenceFieldSerializer.writeObjectData(ReferenceFieldSerializer.java:52)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:489)
    Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.SerializationException: Unable to serialize object of type: org.jboss.mx.notification.ListenerRegistry
Serialization trace:
registries (org.jboss.mx.notification.MBeanServerListenerRegistry)
listeners (org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl)
mbeanServer (org.jboss.classloader.spi.ClassLoaderDomain)
domain (org.jboss.classloading.spi.vfs.policy.VFSClassLoaderPolicy)
delegate (org.jboss.classloader.spi.DelegateLoader)
loader (org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader)
classLoader (flex.messaging.MessageBroker)
messageBroker (flex.messaging.SessionMetricsTracker)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:493)
```

I have been stuck for many days now and not able to fix the issues. Please help

Answer (score 0):

To serialize your HTTPSession, you need to serialize HttpFlexSession and it is probably not serializable (or you are using a strict kryo configuration by disabling serialization on Serializable objects).

You should provide to kryo a class to serialize HttpFlexSession:

```
Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
kryo.register(HttpFlexSession.class, new HttpFlexSessionSerializer(kryo));
```

Then you need to implement HttpFlexSessionSerializer.java that should extend Serializer then you should be able to serialize your flex session with kryo.